# Background-image not displaying online

Tags: css, image, background, background-image

Arg, it's getting frustrating!

None of the solutions on Stack Overflow are working for me, and I just don't know why my `background-image` isn't showing!

I gave it a `background-color`, and it worked fine. Offline you can see the `background-image`, but when I upload my site it's gone. When I type the path of my image, it shows. So it's there.

This is the site:

http://stilld.nl/2014/

In the dark blue area should be my logo.

```
#fade-it{
    background: url('../images/branding.png');
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
    width: 408px;
    height: 500px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

I've tried a ridiculous high `z-index`, still nothing. I tried `opacity: 1`. Nothing. I tried `display: block`. Nothing. I checked the path a thousand times. I used `background:` and `background-image:`. Still nothing.

Hope you guys can help me out!!

Comment: so you are saying the location of your branding image is back one level (from your css file) and in an Images folder there.

Comment: console says that the image couldn't be found, seems like your file location isn;t correct Error: GET http://stilld.nl/2014/images/branding.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: hu? weird... i'll check again. @LukeDuddridge yes.

Comment: @LukeDuddridge the .css is in a folder css. my image is in the folder images. the folders 'images' and 'css' are on the same level. So, in my css I have to go back one step, then enter the folder 'images'.

Comment: @Jop However it seems http://stilld.nl/2014/images/ is a valid folder (403, not 404) - which would lead one to believe the image is named incorrectly.

Comment: O.... my.... I just noticed. my file branding.png start with a capital B........ ARG!!

Comment: @user1737979 - looks nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file `branding.png` does not exist on your live server.  Check it's location and make sure that:

- The file is in the right place;
- The CSS is referring to it correctly.

[image]

For reference, the way your CSS is currently set-up, it attempting to load this image from: http://stilld.nl/2014/images/branding.png. Try clicking the link, you'll see it returns a 404 'not found' error page.

Comment: I found the problem. You cant find branding.png because it was named Branding.png... I forget not using capital letters. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to see you worked it out!  If your question is answered, please do remember to mark the correct answer.  There's a check-mark against each answer, just click the one that answers your question for you.  That way, we can ensure that anyone coming to Stack Overflow in the future with a similar issue will be able to find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path that you have provided is not matching on deployed site. 
Try giving image path as

```
background: url('./images/branding.png');
```

instead of

```
background: url('../images/branding.png');
```

may be this will work

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the image is in the right folder, relative to the URL you're using.

`../images/image.jpg` means "go up one folder, find a folder named "images" and use the image called "image.jpg" inside."

`./images/image.jpg` means "find a folder called "images" in this current folder and use the image called "image.jpg".

`/images/image.jpg` means go to the root folder, find folder "images" and use "image.jpg".

**EDIT: Found it.**
Your image is in /2014/images/. Right now you're trying to make it find the `images` folder inside the `2014` folder. What you can do is set the path to:
`/2014/images/branding.png`

Comment: I found the problem. You cant find branding.png because it was named Branding.png... I forget not using capital letters. Thanks for your help.